# Firebug chokes with embedded YouTube video

Tags: debugging, youtube, firebug

I'm trying to embed a YouTube video in my HTML page. Here's the code that's used to embed a sample video in a page:

`<iframe width="420" height="315" src="//www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/dQw4w9WgXcQ?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>`

This code works just fine in all browsers. It only fails in Firefox **when I have Firebug running.** The errors that occur are:

(1) "JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data"

and if I hit F8 to continue...

(2) "b is undefined"

Any idea what might be causing Firebug to choke? The problem can be easily reproduced with a minimalist HTML page that contains nothing but a HEAD and BODY, where the latter includes the YouTube embed code. But it only fails when Firebug is loaded.

If you *don't* know what's causing the problem, an alternative might be to disable debugging for all code that originates on sites other than my own. So for example, perhaps I could disable debugging for any JavaScript code coming from google.com but allow the debugger to continue working on MY code? Unfortunately, I can't continue debugging my page until this strange issue is resolved.

Comment: It works just fine for me using Firefox 28.0 + Firebug 1.12.7 on Win 8.1. What's your system? Does it also happen on a [fresh Firefox profile with just Firebug installed](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Install_Firebug_into_a_clean_profile)? Maybe it's another extension causing a conflict.

Comment: I am using Mac OSX Mavericks, Firefox 28.0, Firebug 1.12.7. Firebug is the only extension running within Firefox. I only use Firefox for development, so all of my plug-ins (ad blockers, etc.) live on the Chrome side.

Comment: I see. Unfortunately I still can't reproduce this by trying on another Windows machine. You may want to follow the steps described at the [first aid page of Firebug](https://getfirebug.com/firstaid). Maybe a reset of the Firebug settings already helps here. But before doing so you should save your `prefs.js` file somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Mac OSX Mavericks, Firefox 28.0, Firebug 1.12.8.
Simply restarting Firefox did the trick.

Comment: What I ended up doing was using a Chrome extension to *download* the YouTube video to my own machine. Then I referenced that video using the <video> tag. I found it to be less clunky and error prone than referencing YouTube directly, and if you're using a CDN in front of your site (e.g. Cloudfront, Cloudflare), it'll cache the video so that your web servers aren't constantly hammered by users who are viewing it.

Comment: Do you mean that you had this issue even when working online?
I had this problem only with a local copy of my website.